# How To get this script to run on your server - Bash Script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-Type: image/gif"
echo
cat x.gif

OUTPUT=" $QUERY_STRING,$REMOTE_ADDR,$HTTP_USER_AGENT,$HTTP_REFERER,`date`"
echo $OUTPUT >> log.txt

sleep 2.5
```

Comment: Did you try... putting the script in a file and executing it on the command line?

Comment: Presumably it is supposed to be a CGI script, in which case you better say which webserver you are using... and maybe tag with `cgi`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. save the script into some file, for example *script.sh*
2. go to the directory, where the file exists, like `cd my_folder`
3. change file mode to executable with command: `chmod +x script.sh`
4. run the file: `./script.sh`

That should work for you.

I remember, once I was also looking for the answer on exactly the same question.